# Dereference of function pointers

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

When I was browsing the Linux code I encountered the following snippet :

```
static void __init do_initcalls(void)
{
initcall_t *fn;

for (fn = __early_initcall_end; fn < __initcall_end; fn++)
    do_one_initcall(*fn);
}
```

`initcall_t` is a function pointer .

The prototype of `do_initcalls` is `int do_one_initcall(initcall_t fn)` .

So I thought invoking `do_initcalls` would be like `do_one_initcall(fn)` but I see it is `do_one_initcall(*fn)` . Why is that `*fn` instead of only `fn`??

Comment: Why did you think so? You said it yourself: `do_one_initcall` requires an argument of `initcall_t` type. Yet you somehow expect to pass a `initcall_t *` argument to it. Why? If it expects a `initcall_t`, you have to pass an `initcall_t`. That's all. There's no way to answer your question without understanding what strange logic made you ask it. Why would yo want to pass a `initcall_t *` to a function that expects a `initcall_t`?

Comment: @nc3b: I upvoted it to compensate for the downvote. Since the question is clearly expressed and well-formatted, I see no reason for downvoting. Being confused or not knowing something is the whole purpose of asking questions.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev Okay, that's sensible I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `initcall_t` is itself defined as a function pointer, `initcall_t *fn` declares a pointer to a function pointer, and thus the `*` dereferencing operator is applied to get the function pointer.

Here is the definition of the `initcall_t` type:

```
typedef int (*initcall_t)(void);
```

So the type `initcall_t` is already a pointer.